# Does a unit with the "ignores terrain cost" promotion benefit from the "woodsman" promotion?

Tags: civilization-5

Some units, such as scouts, minutemen, or units upgraded from them, get the "ignores terrain cost" promotion which means every terrain tile costs 1 movement point (or less if it's a road). However, the woodsman promotion explicitly says that forests and jungles cost half the movement points.

My question is, how many movements points does a forest tile cost for a unit with both of these promotions? 1.0 or 0.5?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A unit with the "ignores terrain cost" promotion does *not* benefit from the woodsman promotion at all - I've just chose that promotion hoping for 0.5 but instead forest tiles still cost 1.0 movement point :(